# Selenium Web driver - unable to locate element

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to `Selenium-WebDriver`. Trying to locate an element and click on it.

But constantly getting below error:

> unable to locate an element

`Firepath` provided following xpath:

```
"xpath = html/body/header/div/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]"
```

The relevant HTML code is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right top-nav ">
<li class="identity has-icon">
<a href=".......">
</li>
<li class="settings has-icon">
<a href=".......">
<span class="icon icon-cogs" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"/>
**<span class="nav-title">Settings</span>**
</a>
</li>
```

I have tried to find the element in following ways:

```
1. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='right-nav']//a[contains(text(),'Settings')]")).click();

2.  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-title']//a[contains(text(),'Settings')]")).click();

3. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'nav-title')]")).click();
```

Could someone help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not require a `contains` there and that too all of your statement contains `//` twice in xpath which is incorrect.

Please use the below statement

```java
//@ is used to get the span class which is nav-title and 
// whose span text is Settings
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a/span[@class ='nav-title' and . = 'Settings']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Why does adding "//li/a...." to relative path able to find the element but "//span..." shows "Element currently not visible error"?  What does the "." syntax means in the code?

Comment: It is not about just that change alone, it also depends on additional identifying factor with value of the element text using `and`. And would appreciate if you accept it as [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, In last xpath you have used div, instead of that try using span.

```
"//span[contains(@class, 'nav-title')]"
```

Comment: I receive following error: "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on "a (link)" tag directly because inner tags are acting as css only (page looks to be using bootstrap). Try following code, it should work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'PUT href texts here')]")).click()
```

If this is not working , please mention browser and selenium version in the comment.

Comment: @user6507067 I am happy that it worked. Actually you can use this trick to find the xpath of element for the pages which are written in modern web technology frameworks (bootstrap , angular js etc ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the span element with text "Settings". so the below xpath will search for a span element which contains Settings as text inside any anchor tag.

```
.//a/descendant::*[contains(text(),'Settings')]
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: I received "Unable to locate element" for above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below. you will get the element

```
//span[@class='icon icon-cogs']
//span[@class='icon icon-cogs'][@role='presentation']
//span[@class='icon icon-cogs'][@role='presentation']/span
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

This simple CSS selector might work. It's hard to tell if it's unique enough without more of the HTML of the page. It's looking for a `SPAN` tag with the class `nav-title`.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.nav-title")).click();
```

Comment: I receive following error: "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Comment: That means you are finding the right element, now you have to make it visible. I can't help you with that without the page HTML. You'll have to find the element on the page manually and figure out how to make it visible... opening a panel, etc.